# Add exception in jQuery

Tags: jquery, exception, scroll, anchor

I have this code in my header file which scrolls all the pages to a specific anchor.

I want to add an exception for my homepage so the code won't work there.

```
// this code is between <head> tags in my header file.
<script
function scroll(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#scroll').offset().top
    }, 1000);

}
</script>

// this code is at the bottom of the page in my header file
// anchor
<a href="#scroll" id="scroll"></a>

// this code is in the header file
// called
<body onload="scroll()">
```

Comment: what do you mean by want to add exception , why you want your code to fail ?

Comment: One way of doing it is to check you URL if it's on you main page, and if is - disable the scroll.

Comment: what server-side language are you using to create the HTML?  What is there to indicate that the script is currently being run on the homepage

Comment: I dont want the scroll to work on my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can override scroll() function with

```
function scroll(){
 // this function do nothing

}
```

and put it in a suitable place such as at top of page or at the end of page in relevant tags

for example

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function scroll()
{
alert(1);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="scroll()">
body text

<script>
function scroll()
{
alert(2);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this code runs `alert(2)`

Comment: I am using wordpress. How can i find the homepage to place the code there?

Comment: Please see update. put your second overriding before </body> or do some try in your wordpress

Comment: If i do that, the functions scroll dosen't work anymore. I just want to put an exception on the homepage. On my homepage i dont want that script to run, but on the others i want the code active.

Comment: You can put that function in homepage in some where although this is well formed html structure but it will work

Comment: Is there any way to modify the code and put the homepage link as an exception for that code?

Comment: @ElviraEmm I am not wordpress guy, but there is editor that you can modify pages. You can search in wordpress forums